# How to add legends to boxplots with seaborn

Tags: colors, seaborn, legend, boxplot

I have a set of data for which I need to make boxplots. I am having troubles adding legends, with colors appropriate with each single box. Here is my code:

```
model_names=["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h"]
fig = plt.figure()
legend=model_names
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122)
sns.boxplot(data=df_A, ax=ax1, labels=model_names) # Adding model_names here gives errors.
ax1.set_xticklabels([])
ax1.tick_params(axis = "x", which = "both", bottom = False, top = False)

ax1.set_xlabel("A", fontsize=16)
ax1.set_ylabel("Score", fontsize=16)

sns.boxplot(data=df_B, ax=ax2)
ax2.set_xticklabels([])
ax2.tick_params(axis = "x", which = "both", bottom = False, top = False)
ax2.set_xlabel("B", fontsize=16)
```

Here is my dataframe, df_A:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atmPi.png)

and here is the plot, without legends:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFG4W.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seaborn prefers one combined dataframe in ["long form"](http://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/data_structure.html#long-form-vs-wide-form-data). With such a dataframe, a `catplot(kind='box', ...)` can be created using the old column names both for the `x` as for the `hue`. The hue names will end up in the legend.

Here is some example code, showing how to create the "long form" and combine the dataframes.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

model_names = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"]

df_A = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(15, 8), columns=model_names)
df_B = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(20, 8), columns=model_names)
df_A_long = df_A.melt()
df_A_long['source'] = 'A'
df_B_long = df_B.melt()
df_B_long['source'] = 'B'
df_combined = df_A_long.append(df_B_long)

g = sns.catplot(kind='box', data=df_combined, col='source', x='variable', y='value', hue='variable',
                dodge=False, palette=sns.color_palette("Set2"), legend_out=True)
g.add_legend()
plt.setp(g.axes, xticks=[], xlabel='') # remove x ticks and xlabel
g.fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.06) # more space for the y-label
plt.show()
```

[image: box plots of multiple dataframes]

`dfA_long` is created via `pd.melt()` which puts the column names in a new column called "variable" and a column named "value" with the corresponding values. After adding the "source" column it looks like:

```
    variable     value source
0          a  0.581008      A
1          a  0.037324      A
2          a  0.833181      A
....
```

Note that in general having the x-values show the name of each box is clearer than working with a color and referring to a legend. More indirection makes it harder for the viewer to quickly understand the plot. But if e.g. the names would be too long to fit nicely on the x-axis, or when there are many similar subplots, a legend can be a great solution.

Comment: Perfect. Precise and correct. Thanks very much